# assigning a variable in xslt

Tags: xslt

I have the following xsl with me

```
<Root>
    <child>
       <Book name="Title" value="hailey" />
       <Book name="Title" value="After death" />
       <Book name="Price" value="100" />
    </child>
    <child>
       <Book name="Title" value="After death" />
       <Book name="genre" value="fiction" />
    </child>
</Root>
```

I want to iterate through the "child" node and if "Title" is appearing (atleast once), i want a variable to be set. I am using the following code in xslt

```
<xsl:variable name="flag">
        <xsl:for-each select="/Root/Child" >
            <xsl:for-each select="./Book" >
                   <xsl:if test="./@name = 'Title'">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>                     
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>


</xsl:variable>
```

The problem is i the value if variable "flag" is set as "truetruetrue", whereas i want it to be just "true". Any help is appreciated

Comment: Sorry for the delay, it was useful for me. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No need for iteration or conditional instructions at all. Just use this one-liner**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vYourName" select="boolean(/Root/Child/Book[@name='Title'])"/>
```

**For this particular XML document this can be expressed even shorter**:

```
<xsl:variable name="vYourName" select="boolean(/*/*/*[@name='Title'])"/>
```

**Explanation**:

Both definitions define the variable named `"vYourName"` to be `true()` exactly when at least one of the `Root/Child/Book` elements has a `Title` attribute.

**Do note**:

1. By definition the function [**`boolean`**](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/#function-boolean) ($ns) returns true if and only if the nodeset `$ns` is non-empty.
2. The string representation of the boolean value `true()` is the string `"true"`.

**Update**:

In a comment, the OP asked:

> if there is atleast one occurence, is there a way to assign the
>   "value" of that to the variable?

**The answer**: Yes, if by "the value" you mean *the first* `value` attribute, use:

```
 <xsl:variable name="vYourName" select="(/*/*/*[@name='Title'])[1]/@value"/>
```

Comment: As was pointed out in my answer, there is no "Title" attribute

Comment: @freefaller: Thanks for pointing this out -- answer fixed accordingly.

Comment: if there is atleast one occurence, is there a way to assign the "value" of that to the variable?

Comment: @parameswar: Which of the possibly many values? If you always want the first, then use: `(/*/*/*[@name='Title'])[1]/@value`

Answer (score 0):

Untested (and **UPDATED** thanks to the comment from Lucero)...

```
<xsl:variable name="flag">
  <xsl:if test="count(/Root/Child/Book[@name='Title'])>0">true</xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: if Title does not appear in the first hierarchy, variable value is set as null

Comment: Apologies - that was the way I mistakenly read your requirement (to have nothing if there was no Title).  In that case, I would recommend the answer provided by Dimitre (he's a bit of an XSLT god)

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:variable name="flag">
   <xsl:if test="/Root/Child/Book/@name = 'Title'">
      <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>                     
   </xsl:if>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: this only checks the first hierarchy of the tree.

Comment: @parameswar No it checks the full tree for this path - XPath works that way.

Answer (score 0):

**If you like to stick with your code may use**

```
<xsl:variable name="flag">
    <xsl:for-each select="//Book" >
        <xsl:if test="@name = 'Title'">
            <xsl:value-of select="'true'"/>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```